# Doesn't see properly Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

Problem is with dropdown menu in navigation bar. When run this navigation bar in full page mode, you can see whole navigation bar and a part of Dropdown. If you click on this, dropdown menu doesn't show properly. You can see just a little white part and that's it. My question is how to see whole dropdown menu.

```css
.demo{
background-color:blue;
height: 10000px;
}
  
.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.logo img{
  height:60px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 5000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .menuul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black .menuul {
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

nav .menuul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav .menuul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media(min-width:1025px){

nav .menuul li a:hover { COLOR: white; TEXT-DECORATION: none; font-weight: bold; transition: width .3s ease-in-out;}

nav .menuul li a:after{ 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FD3C3D;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;}

nav .menuul li a:hover:after {width: 40%;}

}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 24px 0px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 1025px) {
 
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .logo img{
    height:40px;
  }

  nav .menuul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  }

  nav.black .menuul {
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  }

  .showing {
    max-height: 34em;
  }

  nav .menuul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 24px 0px 24px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }

  nav .menuul li a:hover { COLOR: white; text-decoration: none;}
}

.usluge:hover .usluge-cont {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  z-index: 10000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">
  <nav>
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menuul">
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu#2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu#3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu#4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because your `nav .menuul` has `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove "[overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)" property from "nav .menuul".
Here is working code:

```css
.demo{
background-color:blue;
height: 10000px;
}
  
.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.logo img{
  height:60px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 5000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .menuul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black .menuul {
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

nav .menuul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav .menuul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media(min-width:1025px){

nav .menuul li a:hover { COLOR: white; TEXT-DECORATION: none; font-weight: bold; transition: width .3s ease-in-out;}

nav .menuul li a:after{ 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #FD3C3D;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;}

nav .menuul li a:hover:after {width: 40%;}

}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 24px 0px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 1025px) {
 
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .logo img{
    height:40px;
  }

  nav .menuul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  }

  nav.black .menuul {
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  }

  .showing {
    max-height: 34em;
  }

  nav .menuul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 24px 0px 24px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }

  nav .menuul li a:hover { COLOR: white; text-decoration: none;}
}

.usluge:hover .usluge-cont {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  z-index: 10000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">
  <nav>
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menuul">
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu#2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu#3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu#4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```